# Freezing point of seawater for given salinity and pressure

Tags: c#

I have a simple program implemented by me that should calculate the freezing temperature of the seas and oceans. The program works well, only because it offers other results than some online calculators.

https://www.mt-oceanography.info/Utilities/freeze.html

For example, the link above shows a result:
salinity:12
pressure (10 kPa):2
 T = -0.651
But my program shows this result:
salinity:12
pressure:2
T= -1.400587
Source code:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter salinity: ");
        string s = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter pressure: ");
        string p = Console.ReadLine();
        double t = FreezePointCalc(float.Parse(s), float.Parse(p)) / 1000;
        Console.WriteLine(t.ToString());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    private static double FreezePointCalc(float salinity, float pressure)
    {
        double A0 = -0.0575;
        double A1 = 1.710523 * Math.E - 3;
        double A2 = -2.154996 * Math.E - 4;
        double b = -7.53 * Math.E - 4;
        double f_Point = A0 * salinity + A1 * salinity * Math.Sqrt(salinity) + A2 * salinity * salinity + b * pressure;
        return Math.Round(1000 * f_Point) / 1000;
    }
```

I want to know what went wrong and where I went wrong. Thanks in advance everyone.

Comment: I'm not sure that `1.710523 * Math.E - 3` does what you want it to do. Did you debug your program to check the values of `A1` and `A2`?

Comment: no, these are constants according to the formula.

Comment: But they're the wrong constants. `1.710523e-3 == 0,001710523`. `1.710523 * Math.E - 3 == 1,64968358806125`.

Comment: yes, but Math.E is not equal to e?

Comment: `Math.E` is the natural logarithmic base aka `e` (=2.71828182845905)

Comment: and a literal number written with e, without spaces, is written in `exponential notation` - the e stands for exponent. `1e0 == 1, 1e1 == 10, 1e2 == 100`. Math.E is the mathematical constant `e`, which is what @Rafalon described.

Comment: hmmm ....oh well i got it right

Comment: First you should double check if you actually need `1.710523 * (10^-3)` or `1.710523^-3` which are two different things

Comment: Also note you have an unnecessary `/ 1000` in the `main` method, making the answer come out in thousands of C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my search the formula of freezing point of seawater based in salinity and pressure is

> (-0.0575 + 1.710523E-3 * Sqrt (Abs (S)) - 2.154996E-4 * S) * S -
>   7.53E-4 * P;

Which can be translated to c# as code

```
private static double FreezePointCalc(float salinity, float pressure)
{
   double A0 = -0.0575;
   double A1 = 1.710523E-3;
   double A2 = 2.154996E-4;
   double b = 7.53E-4;
   double f_Point = (A0 + A1 * Math.Sqrt(Math.Abs(salinity)) - A2 * salinity) * salinity - b * pressure;
   return Math.Round(1000 * f_Point);
 }
```

Comment: Hey, for those who can give me some info.I want to know where or where these values came from:
  double A0 = -0.0575;
   double A1 = 1.710523E-3;
   double A2 = 2.154996E-4;
   double b = 7.53E-4;

Comment: @AnghelinaGuznac weird question since you already had came to those values, but got the formula from here http://www.code10.info/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=66:calculating-the-freezing-point-of-seawater&catid=54:cat_coding_algorithms_seawater&Itemid=79